# Why is my proof for “if $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 2$, then $-x^3 + 4x + 1 > 0$” is false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

> $$\text{if $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 2$, then $-x^3 + 4x + 1 > 0$}$$

$$x(4-x^2)>-1$$
$$x>\dfrac{1}{x^2-4}$$ if the last statement is smaller than $x$ then it is also smaller than $2$ because of first statement ($0 \leqslant x \leqslant 2$):
$$\dfrac{1}{x^2-4}<2$$
$$1<2x^2-8$$
$$4.5<x^2$$
$$-2.121<x<2.121$$
Which contradicts the first statement because $x$ cannot be greater than $2$. My proof is wrong but why? (I took that question from Math for Computer Science book p. 12)

Comment: You divide by 0 when x = 2.

Comment: In your third line you (must have) assumed $4-x^2>0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made two mistakes and recovered:
$$\dfrac{1}{x^2-4}<2 \not\Rightarrow 1<2(x^2-4) \ \ (\text{it must be} \ 1\color{red}>2(x^2-4), \text{because} \ x^2-4\le 0)\\
4.5<x^2 \not\Rightarrow -2.121<x<2.121 \ (\text{it must be} \ 4.5\color{red}>x^2 \Rightarrow -2.121<x<2.121)$$

Alternatively, you can prove it as follows:
$$-x^3 + 4x + 1 > 0 \iff x^3-4x-1<0 \iff x(x-2)(x+2)<1 \iff \\
x(x-2)(x+2)\le 0<1 \ \ \text{for} \  0\le x\le 2 \ \text{(why?)}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that $-3/\sqrt2<x<3/\sqrt2$ because $x$ still lies between $0$ and $2$. You have found a wider bound for $x$, but it is not wrong. Note that the larger interval does not mean that $x$ takes all values between $\pm3/\sqrt2$.

An analogy could be that $x=3$, and we know that $2<x<4$. But it is also true that $-1<x<7$, or even $-\infty<x<\infty$.

Comment: So, does the last statement mean "x can be any number between -2.121 and 2.121" or "x is one of the numbers between -2.121 and 2.121 but we don't know which number is it" ?

Comment: We know that $0\le x\le2$. Therefore the last statement is saying that $x$ can be a set of numbers between $\pm2.121$ but is restricted to $[0,2]$ due to the criterion at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Stating that a statement is smaller than a number makes no sense.

And from the fact that $\dfrac1{x^2-4}<2$ together with $0\leqslant x\leqslant2$, you can't deduce that $\dfrac1{x^2-4}<x$.

Finally, from $\dfrac1{x^2-4}<2$, what you deduce is that $1>x(x^2-4)$, since $x^2-4<0$.

Answer (score 0):

1 + 4x - x$^3$ = 1 + x(4 - x$^2$).
For all x in [0,2], 0 < x, 0 < 4 - x$^2$.
Desired conclusion quickly follows.